# Java: Palindrome in both bases

Tags: java, radix, palindrome

Okay so I have no idea about how to do this problem! I need to write a code that will find the sum of all numbers less than 1 million that are palindromes in both base 10 and base 2.

Could someone please help me get this problem started!

Comment: Generate palindromes in base 10. Sum them. Generate palindromes in base 2. Convert to base 10, sum them. Add two sums.

Comment: Read this first: [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Deltharis You're obviously wrong. OP: What's the problem? Loop over all numbers below 1 million. Check palindrome base 10. Check palindrome base 2. If both are satisfied, add to accumulator.

Comment: write a function that returns true if a number is a palindrome (works for both bases). then loop from 1 to 1,000,000 check for very number if its a palindrome base 10, if so check if its a palindrome base 2, if so, add to sum

Comment: @maaartinus am I `obviously` wrong? I'm no native speaker, I could be wrong, but it sounds like this sentence could mean the equivalent of `sum of all numbers less then 1 million that are palindromes in base 10 and those that are palindromes in base 2`. Imagine pausing between `palindromes` and `in` to see it.

Comment: "less than 1M" in what base? 1,000,000 in base 2 is 64 in base 10...

Comment: @fge 1000000 in base 2 is not a million.

Comment: @khelwood hence my question; read my comment again

Comment: @Deltharis I'm no native speaker either. Somehow the meaning I assumed seems to be obvious to me, but maybe just because to me the other task makes little sense (to me, again). Assuming your interpretation, your solution is not wrong.

Comment: @fge What I'm saying is, "Less than 1 million" is unambiguous. There is only one number that is "1 million".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is pretty forward, it's just a bruteforce over all palindrome numbers bellow 1M.

```
public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int count=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 1_000_000; i++) {
            if (isDoublePalindrome(""+i)) {
                count+=i;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(count);

    }

     public static boolean isPalindrome(String N){
        return new StringBuilder(N).reverse().toString().equals(""+N);
    }

    public static String toBinary(String N){

        return Long.toBinaryString(Long.parseLong(N));
    }

    public static boolean isDoublePalindrome(String N){

        if(isPalindrome(N) && isPalindrome(toBinary(N))) return true;
        return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The rest is up to you, but here is a method which will tell you whether an `int` is a palindrome in a given base; supposes that the arguments are correct, ie the number to check is >= 0 and the base is > 0:

```
public static isPalindromInBase(final int before, final int base)
{
    int after = 0;

    for (int i = before; i > 0; i /= base) {
        after += i % base;
        after *= base;
    }

    return before == after;
}
```